# Building map and Path Planning using Rasberry Pi 3b+ and Kinect Xbox360

Tags: ros, path-planning, kinect, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to build map and path planning for a mobile robot with low cost so I intend to use Rasberry Pi 3b+ and Kinect 360. I will handle all the things remotely in ROS Master ( PC) and Pib3+ pluged with kinect on mobile robot. Will it work?
Thanks for reading

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345518/building-map-and-path-planning-using-rasberry-pi-3b+-and-kinect-xbox360/) by [drtritm](https://answers.ros.org/users/50806/drtritm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2020-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @drtritm,

I say the set up you are describing will work since one of my projects was exactly that. However, since you are only using the raspberry pi as a the Kinect "driver" I would recommend to distribute the different tasks you want perform between machines. Tasks like mapping will perform better and faster with more computing power, besides take into account possible communication delays between your PC and the Raspberry Pi.

If you want some info on the know-how you can check the kinect drivers [here](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_kinect) or [here](http://wiki.ros.org/libfreenect), the ros [navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) for path planning, [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) for static map generation (You will able to find more [tools](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) like that apart from gmapping) and localization tools like [robot localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) and, since you will be using a static map, [AMCL](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl). In your set up it will make more sense to use AMCL with your generated map instead of robot localization.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drtritm](https://answers.ros.org/users/50806/drtritm/) on 2020-03-02**:
Hi, If you can did it, could you tell me what kind of OS in your raspberry pi 3b+, and which version of ROS. I'm using Melodic with Ubuntu Mate, after hours struggling to install Kinect with Raspberry, still not work

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-03-02**:
Well, It was a couple of years ago but I used a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with ROS Kinetic under Ubuntu Mate Xenial (16.04). If you are using Melodic you will need Ubuntu 18.04 and Openni drivers since freenect is not supported on Melodic. I am sure with PINN you will be able to install both OS.